# Set Display Value in Dropdown List Based on Selection

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I have a standard drop down list and I would like it to display the `VALUE` when closed but the text when expanded for selection.  For example, based on my code below, if the user selects `'Item 3'` from the list, 3 should be displayed when the list is closed.  I'm to the point where I can get the value selected but I don't know how to rewrite what is displayed in the drop down list.

Appreciate any help!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setValue()
{
    var value=document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
    //Don't know what to put here
}
</script>

<select name="mySelect" id="mySelect" onchange="setValue();">
    <option value="1" selected="">Item 1</option>
    <option value="2">Item 2</option>
    <option value="3">Item 3</option>
    <option value="4">Item 4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Do you want to print the selected value and selected item text in a span tag?

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  No, my preference would be to just change the displayed text in the dropdown when it is collapsed to the value of the selected item.

Comment: Can you check it out my answer? Let me know if this works for you, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the `mySelect` variable which contains the `<select>` DOM. Then by using `mySelect`, you can get the attributes of the `<select>` tag.

```
var mySelect = document.getElementById("mySelect");
```

Then, you can access to the `mySelect` options which is an array.

```
mySelect.options[]
```

`mySelect.selectedIndex` will give you the current selected index of the  tag.

Finally, by appending the `.text` attribute, you can set the new value of the current selection.

```
mySelect.options[mySelect.selectedIndex].text = mySelect.value;
```

**Something like this:**

```js
function setValue() {
  var mySelect = document.getElementById("mySelect");
  mySelect.options[mySelect.selectedIndex].text = mySelect.value;
}
```

```html
<select name="mySelect" id="mySelect" onchange="setValue();">
  <option value="1" selected="">Item 1</option>
  <option value="2">Item 2</option>
  <option value="3">Item 3</option>
  <option value="4">Item 4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @Danny This replaces the drop down text. The question was if the display value can be shown as the selected value. Not sure why this was accepted as this mutates the text with each selection